# Convert string representation of list to list without using any packages

Tags: python, list

(the exception is pandas and numpy can be used)

Without using any packages, how can I convert '[np.nan,2,3,4]' to [np.nan,2,3,4]?

Keep in mind, eval('[np.nan,2,3,4]') doesn't work as it throws an error due to the null element

Comment: how do you deal with `np.nan` without using numpy?

Comment: yep i have numpy and pandas, figured that couldn't solve the issue as no other answers used those packages

Comment: so what happens to it? it becomes a string?

Answer (score 0):

so if your array just has floats and ints with few nan, just check for nan and convert others to int

if you want to keep floats, convert everything except to floats, just add one more line that converts complete floats to int

```
s = '[np.nan,2,3,4]' 
nan = np.nan # if you can use np
nan = float('nan') #if you can't use np
s = [int(i.strip()) if 'nan' not in i else nan for i in s[1:-1].split(',')]
```

```
[nan, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
inputs = '[np.nan,2,3,4]'
elements = inputs[1:-1].split(",")
output_list = []
for element in elements:
    if element == "np.nan":
        output_list.append(np.nan)
    else:   # Handles ints, or throws ValueError
        try:
            output_list.append(int(element))
        except:
            print(f'Token {element} cannot be converted to an integer')
>>> print(output_list)
[nan, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to handle more cases (floats, other inputs), add more cases.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine without any `numpy`:

```
>>> a = '[np.nan,2,3,4]'
>>> parts = a[1:-1].split(',')
>>> parts
['np.nan', '2', '3', '4']
>>> [float('nan') if i == 'np.nan' else int(i) for i in parts]
[nan, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is very interesting. Actually, you have come up with a good idea that is eval function.It is useful for this case.Maybe you forget to import numpy, therefore it throws an error.

[Here is my solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKm79.png)